# how to force Eclipse CDT to add -stdc++11 flag on every project

Tags: eclipse, c++11, mingw, eclipse-cdt, mingw-w64

I have a problem in that Eclipse with C++ support doesn't use C++11 (or 14) with the default project settings, I have to go to:

Project Settings > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Dialect > Language standard > ISO C++11

Is there any way to change the default project so that it ALWAYS adds the -stdc++11 flag be default? I always make a project with Hello World C++ Project and use MinGW GCC.

I've read some previous questions talking about a makefile something, but no step-by-step guide.

Versions:

Windows 10

Eclipse Luna 20150109-0600

MinGW with C++11 support 100% (maybe even C++14) 4.8.1

Answer (score 3):

The CDT-based [Cevelop C++ IDE](http://cevelop.com) provides what you need. It's essentially CDT Mars with many plugins that help you write better C++11/14 code.

It features a Plug-in called "Elevenator", which automatically configures projects to use C++11.

You can find the Elevenator documentation [Here](http://cute-test.com/projects/cute/wiki/Elevenator)

If you don't want to use cevelop, you can also install Elevenator manually from this updatesite: http://www.cute-test.com/updatesite/mars

It is located in the category CUTE optional features.